# how can i clear inputs after insert into database with ajax and php?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I would like to clear the inputs after the user submit the form using ajax.

My code works fine, i made based tutorials and after send fields are still with values. I want to clean them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#inserir").click(function(){
    $('#loadingDiv')
        .hide()  
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        })
    ;
var nome=$("#nome").val();
var email=$("#email").val();
var confirmacao=$("#confirmacao").val();
var acompanhantes=$("#acompanhantes").val();
// loading image
$("#message").html('<center><img src="images/ajax.gif" /></center>');

$.post('inserir.php', {nome: nome, email: email, confirmacao: confirmacao, acompanhantes: acompanhantes},
function(data){
$("#message").html(data);
$("#message").hide();
$("#message").fadeIn(500); 
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Php

```
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $confirmacao = $_POST['confirmacao'];
 $acompanhantes = $_POST['acompanhantes'];
//Insert Data into mysql
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO cadastro_rsvp(nome,email,confirmacao,acompanhantes,id) VALUES('$nome','$email','$confirmacao','$acompanhantes','')");
 mysql_close($con);

if($query){
echo "Dados enviados";
}
else{ echo "Erro!"; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will clear all textbox, textarea, radio button, checkbox values:
replace "**#myFormId**" with your form id.

```
$('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea', '#myFormId').val('');
$('input:checkbox, input:radio', '#myFormId').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

you must add it after this line in your code:

```
$("#message").fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: I used your code, the only field that is not cleared is the email. you can tell me why? Thanx very much!

Comment: If u are using html5 input types the u must add that also, for email will be like `input:text, input:email`

Comment: My input is <input placeholder="Seu email" type="email" name="email" id="email" required> and i change to $('input:text, input:email, input:file, select, textarea', '#myFormId').val(''); but not cleared. Is right? The other fields are Ok.

Comment: if that is not working u can use `$("#email").val("");` after the code I gave.

Answer (score 1):

An example using one of your fields:

```
$("#nome").val('');
```

The above code will basically blank whatever is in the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

I use HTML to do it.

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: or use $().val('') each field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear your fields **AFTER** you save it into the database, you'll have to clear your inputs **AFTER** you get a response from the server, in this case, in the `success` of your `$.post`.

```
$.post('inserir.php',
  {nome: nome, email: email, confirmacao: confirmacao, acompanhantes: acompanhantes},
  function(data){
    $("#message").html(data);
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#message").fadeIn(500);
    //HERE YOU PERFORM THE RESET (I suppose that they are input text fields):
    $("#nome").val('');
    $("#email").val('');
    $("#confirmacao").val('');
    $("#acompanhantes").val('');
  });
  return false;
});
```

Also, check the [jQuery.post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more information to work directly with a success callback function.